# if statement is not working in Django HTML template

Tags: python, html, django, if-statement, templates

```
<div class="row icon-boxes">
        {% for feature in features %}
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3 d-flex align-items-stretch mb-5 mb-lg-0" data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-delay="200">
          <div class="icon-box">
            <div class="icon"><i class="ri-stack-line"></i></div>
            <h4 class="title"><a href="">{{feature.name}}</a></h4>
            <p class="description">{{feature.details}}</p>
            **{% if feature.is_true == True %}
            <p> Yes this is True</p>
            {% endif %}**
            
          </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
```

I am just trying to use the if statement here.
feature is the object of a class which has an attribute is_true which contains boolean values. I am trying to check if it is true then display the following paragraph else not.

Eveything else seems to work fine.
On runing the server Eveyrthing is dispalyed on the page except for the part in the if condition.

Please help me get this right, I am new to Django. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Boollean values are not the same in Django templates as in python code. Inside the if statement `{% if feature.is_true == True %}` , `True` is considered a variable, which has not been defined yet. `True` evaluates to `None`, making the whole statement `False`.

Changing it to `{% if feature.is_true %}` should work.

Comment: i think it works too `{% if variable_name == True %}`